# JFormattedTextfield, doesn't show the format

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

i'm new to java and i have a problem with my JFormattedTextField. It doesn't show the format, just the same plain text like it was without format. I think i might have done something wrong but I can't figure out what. I don't have any errors.

```
package gipsofo;

import static Database.Databasecon.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class Panel_Klantgegevens extends JPanel {

    private JLabel nummer, naam, straat, postcode, gemeente, telefoonnummer;
    private JLabel geboortedatum;
    public JTextField txtnummer, txtnaam, txtstraat;
    public JTextField txtgemeente;
    public JButton ophalen, veranderen, aanmaken, verwijderen;
    public JFormattedTextField txttelefoonnummer, txtpostcode, txtgeboortedatum;
    public Font font;
    public JComboBox Operatie;

    public Panel_Klantgegevens() {
        try{
        MaskFormatter tel = new MaskFormatter("####/##.##.##");
        tel.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
        txttelefoonnummer = new JFormattedTextField(tel);
        MaskFormatter post = new MaskFormatter("####");
        post.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
        txtpostcode = new JFormattedTextField(post);
        MaskFormatter geboorte = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
        geboorte.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
        txtgeboortedatum = new JFormattedTextField(geboorte);
        } catch (ParseException Ex){
            System.out.println(Ex);
        }

        setLayout(null);



        txtpostcode = new JFormattedTextField();
        txtpostcode.setFont(font);
        txttelefoonnummer = new JFormattedTextField();
        txttelefoonnummer.setFont(font);
        txtgeboortedatum = new JFormattedTextField();
        txtgeboortedatum.setFont(font);

        nummer.setBounds(15, 60, 130, 30);
        txtnummer.setBounds(155, 60, 130, 30);
        naam.setBounds(15, 100, 130, 30);
        txtnaam.setBounds(155, 100, 130, 30);
        straat.setBounds(15, 140, 130, 30);
        txtstraat.setBounds(155, 140, 130, 30);
        postcode.setBounds(15, 180, 130, 30);
        txtpostcode.setBounds(155, 180, 130, 30);
        gemeente.setBounds(15, 220, 130, 30);
        txtgemeente.setBounds(155, 220, 130, 30);
        telefoonnummer.setBounds(15, 260, 130, 30);
        txttelefoonnummer.setBounds(155, 260, 130, 30);
        geboortedatum.setBounds(15, 300, 130, 30);
        txtgeboortedatum.setBounds(155, 300, 130, 30);
        ophalen.setBounds(15, 340, 130, 30);
        veranderen.setBounds(155, 340, 130, 30);
        aanmaken.setBounds(15, 340, 130, 30);
        verwijderen.setBounds(155, 340, 130, 30);
        Operatie.setBounds(15, 20, 170, 30);

        txtnummer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        txtnaam.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        txtstraat.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        txtpostcode.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        txtgemeente.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        txttelefoonnummer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        txtgeboortedatum.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

        add(nummer);
        add(txtnummer);
        add(naam);
        add(txtnaam);
        add(straat);
        add(txtstraat);
        add(postcode);
        add(txtpostcode);
        add(gemeente);
        add(txtgemeente);
        add(telefoonnummer);
        add(txttelefoonnummer);
        add(geboortedatum);
        add(txtgeboortedatum);
        add(ophalen);
        add(veranderen);
        add(aanmaken);
        add(verwijderen);
        add(Operatie);



        Operatie.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post the relevant piece of code, and not everything? It makes it a bit more readable for future people ;)

Comment: The currently posted code is too broken for anyone to try to help you.  It's common to forget that the JFormattedTextField's 'text' and 'value' properties are two separate things.  See here for details:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html